# KnockoutJS elements not rendered once loaded via Jquery Ajax function

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, requirejs, magento2

I have loaded a sidebar over ajax however this html uses knockoutJS to render completely. I am wondering how to execute the KnockoutJs portions of this code.

The content below is loaded via jQuery ajax function and contains a number of knockout elements as well as some X Magento Init type scripts:

```
<div class=\"block filter\" id=\"layered-filter-block\" data-mage-init='{\"collapsible\":{\"openedState\": \"active\", \"collapsible\": true, \"active\": false, \"collateral\": { \"openedState\": \"filter-active\", \"element\": \"body\" } }}'>
<div class=\"block-title filter-title\" data-count=\"0\">
    <strong data-role=\"title\">Shop By<\/strong>
<\/div>
    <div class=\"block-content filter-content\">
        <strong role=\"heading\" aria-level=\"2\" class=\"block-subtitle filter-subtitle\">Shopping Options<\/strong>
            <div class=\"filter-options\" id=\"narrow-by-list\" data-role=\"content\" data-mage-init='{\"accordion\":{\"openedState\": \"active\", \"collapsible\": true, \"active\": [0,1,2], \"multipleCollapsible\": true}}'>
                <div data-role=\"collapsible\" class=\"filter-options-item\">
                    <div data-role=\"title\" class=\"filter-options-title\">Category<\/div>
                    <div data-role=\"content\" class=\"filter-options-content\">\n<ol class=\"items\">
                        <li class=\"item\">
                            <a href=\"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/catalogsearch\/result\/index\/?ajax=1&amp;cat=143&amp;q=ice+machine\">Front of House
                            <span class=\"count\">2<span class=\"filter-count-label\">items<\/span><\/span><\/a>
                        <\/li>
                        <li class=\"item\">
                            <a href=\"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/catalogsearch\/result\/index\/?ajax=1&amp;cat=182&amp;q=ice+machine\">Bar Supplies
                            <span class=\"count\">4<span class=\"filter-count-label\">items<\/span><\/span><\/a>
                        <\/li>
                        <li class=\"item\">
                            <a href=\"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/catalogsearch\/result\/index\/?ajax=1&amp;cat=257&amp;q=ice+machine\">Catering Equipment<span class=\"count\">111<span class=\"filter-count-label\">\n 
                            items                        <\/span><\/span>\n       
                            <\/a>\n                    <\/li>\n 
                            <li class=\"item\">\n                    
                            <a href=\"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/catalogsearch\/result\/index\/?ajax=1&amp;cat=342&amp;q=ice+machine\">\n           
                            Warewashing                                            <span class=\"count\">\n                        
                            3                        <span class=\"filter-count-label\">\n           
                            items                        <\/span><\/span>\n                     
                            <\/a>\n                    <\/li>\n            <li class=\"item\">\n         
                            <a href=\"http:\/\/www.domain.com\/catalogsearch\/result\/index\/?ajax=1&amp;cat=521&amp;q=ice+machine\">\n          
                            Catering Equipment Offers                                            <span class=\"count\">\n                            1         
                            <span class=\"filter-count-label\">\n                                                    item                        <\/span><\/span>\n         
                            <\/a>\n                    <\/li>\
                            <\/ol>
                            <\/div>\n                    
                            <\/div>\n                                                        
                            <div data-role=\"collapsible\" class=\"filter-options-item\">                
                            <div data-role=\"title\" class=\"filter-options-title\">Brand<\/div>\n    

                            <div data-role=\"content\" class=\"filter-options-content\">
                                <div data-bind=\"scope: 'brandFilter'\">
                                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --> <!-- \/ko -->
                                <\/div>
                                <script type=\"text\/x-magento-init\">
                                    {\"*\" : {\"Magento_Ui\/js\/core\/app\": {\"components\": {\"brandFilter\": {\"component\":\"Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog\\\/js\\\/attribute-filter\",\"maxSize\":10,\"displayProductCount\":true,\"hasMoreItems\":true,\"ajaxLoadUrl\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalog\\\/navigation_filter\\\/ajax\\\/?ajax=1&filterName=brand&q=ice+machine\",\"items\":[{\"label\":\"Scotsman\",\"count\":41,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Scotsman&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Hoshizaki\",\"count\":15,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Hoshizaki&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Ice-o-matic\",\"count\":12,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Ice-o-matic&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Blue Ice\",\"count\":7,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Blue+Ice&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Graupel\",\"count\":7,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Graupel&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Nemox\",\"count\":7,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Nemox&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Manitowoc\",\"count\":6,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Manitowoc&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Polar Refrigeration\",\"count\":5,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Polar+Refrigeration&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Longo & Co\",\"count\":4,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Longo+%26+Co&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"Beaumont\",\"count\":3,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&brand=Beaumont&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false}]}}}}}\n<\/script>\n\n<\/div>\n                    <\/div>\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <div data-role=\"collapsible\" class=\"filter-options-item\">\n                        <div data-role=\"title\" class=\"filter-options-title\">Power<\/div>\n                        <div data-role=\"content\" class=\"filter-options-content\"><div data-bind=\"scope: 'power_ddFilter'\">\n    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --> <!-- \/ko -->\n<\/div>\n\n<script type=\"text\/x-magento-init\">\n    {\"*\" : {\"Magento_Ui\/js\/core\/app\": {\"components\": {\"power_ddFilter\": {\"component\":\"Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog\\\/js\\\/attribute-filter\",\"maxSize\":10,\"displayProductCount\":true,\"hasMoreItems\":false,\"ajaxLoadUrl\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalog\\\/navigation_filter\\\/ajax\\\/?ajax=1&filterName=power_dd&q=ice+machine\",\"items\":[{\"label\":\"13 Amp (Plug)\",\"count\":111,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&power_dd=13+Amp+%28Plug%29&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false},{\"label\":\"1 Phase (Hard Wired)\",\"count\":2,\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&power_dd=1+Phase+%28Hard+Wired%29&q=ice+machine\",\"is_selected\":false}]}}}}}\n<\/script>\n\n<\/div>\n                    <\/div>\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <div data-role=\"collapsible\" class=\"filter-options-item\">\n                        <div data-role=\"title\" class=\"filter-options-title\">Price<\/div>\n                        <div data-role=\"content\" class=\"filter-options-content\"><div class=\"smile-es-range-slider\" data-role=\"range-price-slider-price\">\n    <div data-role=\"from-label\"><\/div>\n    <div data-role=\"to-label\"><\/div>\n    <div data-role=\"slider-bar\"><\/div>\n    <div class=\"actions-toolbar\">\n        <div data-role=\"message-box\"><\/div>\n        <div class=\"actions-primary\">\n            <a class=\"action primary small\" data-role=\"apply-range\">\n                <span>OK<\/span>\n            <\/a>\n        <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n<\/div>\n\n<script type=\"text\/x-magento-init\">\n    { \"[data-role=range-price-slider-price]\" : { \"rangeSlider\" : {\"minValue\":1,\"maxValue\":6091,\"currentValue\":{\"from\":1,\"to\":6091},\"fieldFormat\":{\"pattern\":\"\\u00a3%s\",\"precision\":2,\"requiredPrecision\":2,\"decimalSymbol\":\".\",\"groupSymbol\":\",\",\"groupLength\":3,\"integerRequired\":false},\"intervals\":[{\"value\":1,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3,\"count\":1},{\"value\":40,\"count\":1},{\"value\":60,\"count\":1},{\"value\":64,\"count\":1},{\"value\":150,\"count\":1},{\"value\":179,\"count\":1},{\"value\":190,\"count\":1},{\"value\":242,\"count\":1},{\"value\":291,\"count\":1},{\"value\":325,\"count\":1},{\"value\":355,\"count\":2},{\"value\":395,\"count\":1},{\"value\":465,\"count\":1},{\"value\":472,\"count\":1},{\"value\":515,\"count\":1},{\"value\":520,\"count\":1},{\"value\":535,\"count\":1},{\"value\":555,\"count\":1},{\"value\":577,\"count\":1},{\"value\":585,\"count\":1},{\"value\":599,\"count\":1},{\"value\":605,\"count\":2},{\"value\":615,\"count\":1},{\"value\":640,\"count\":1},{\"value\":658,\"count\":1},{\"value\":685,\"count\":1},{\"value\":705,\"count\":1},{\"value\":730,\"count\":1},{\"value\":745,\"count\":2},{\"value\":785,\"count\":1},{\"value\":805,\"count\":1},{\"value\":830,\"count\":1},{\"value\":895,\"count\":2},{\"value\":925,\"count\":1},{\"value\":965,\"count\":1},{\"value\":970,\"count\":1},{\"value\":990,\"count\":2},{\"value\":1030,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1065,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1080,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1085,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1095,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1105,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1130,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1155,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1225,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1235,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1240,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1259,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1310,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1360,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1365,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1450,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1485,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1495,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1510,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1580,\"count\":2},{\"value\":1605,\"count\":2},{\"value\":1685,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1710,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1779,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1785,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1865,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1870,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1885,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1890,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1970,\"count\":1},{\"value\":1995,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2000,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2050,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2130,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2199,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2220,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2345,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2350,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2360,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2405,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2415,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2445,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2450,\"count\":2},{\"value\":2480,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2500,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2530,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2565,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2570,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2595,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2695,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2730,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2825,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2850,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2950,\"count\":1},{\"value\":2995,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3010,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3025,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3145,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3205,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3295,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3300,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3485,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3495,\"count\":1},{\"value\":3580,\"count\":1},{\"value\":4015,\"count\":1},{\"value\":4075,\"count\":1},{\"value\":4305,\"count\":1},{\"value\":4310,\"count\":1},{\"value\":4595,\"count\":1},{\"value\":4620,\"count\":1},{\"value\":5250,\"count\":1},{\"value\":5355,\"count\":1},{\"value\":6090,\"count\":1}],\"urlTemplate\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.domain.com\\\/catalogsearch\\\/result\\\/index\\\/?ajax=1&price=<%- from %>-<%- to %>&q=ice+machine\",\"messageTemplates\":{\"displayCount\":\"<%- count %> products\",\"displayEmpty\":\"No products in the selected range.\"},\"rate\":1} 
                                    } }
                                <\/script>
                            <\/div>
                <\/div>
            <\/div>
        <\/div>
    <\/div>
```

These are then added to a block on my page via html jQuery method:

```
$(sidebarBlock).html(this.filters);
```

Looking at the DOM I cannot actually see the scripts however they are there in response when reviewing with `console.log()`. Similarly the below shows the scripts are present:

```
$(sidebar).find("script").each(function() {
  console.log("found a script");
}
```

I have tried to use `.trigger('contentUpdated');` like below:

```
document.getElementById("layered-filter-block").innerHTML = this.filters;
$(sidebarBlock).trigger('contentUpdated');
```

and:

```
$(sidebarBlock).html(this.filters);
$(sidebarBlock).trigger('contentUpdated');
```

and by reapplying bindings for knockout:

```
ko.cleanNode($('#layered-filter-block'));
ko.applyBindings($('#layered-filter-block'));
```

The above throws an error about bindings already being applied however but I have used cleanNode before to unbind however error persists.

Comment: *"I have loaded a sidebar over ajax"* How? Show the code, and the relevant code of the sidebar itself.

Comment: @Tomalak I have added the json response but have just used jQuery ajax method to get this json aswell as append and other similar methods to add the content to the page but the scripts do not show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed issue for me:

```
$(sidebarBlock).applyBindings();
```

> https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-uicomponent-reinit-ajax-reload/

Comment: I have Knockout components loaded on category page template, and pagination causes the `.html template` not to be sent when ajax result is sent.  If you can perhaps remember, or check please; would I need to apply this at the BOTTOM of the `list.phtml (for category page)`.  This will be an issue as I have unique IDs as each component is for one product on the page (so **multiple components** : one component per product that needs this component).  `scope: 'gallery-scope-<?= $__productId ?>`  What does sidebarBlock selector represent here?  The 'scoped element'?

Comment: I would appreciate if you can assist on my above question.  Thanks!